# Кастомизация ProgressBar

Tags: android, xml

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно кастомизировать ProgressBar в шаблоне XML-разметки, чтобы получился такой результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ПРобовал по разному но не могу совместить виджет ProgressBar с картинкой...

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android

Comment: в принципе понял как кастомизировать полоску, но не понятно - как наложить ее на рисунок

Comment: как вариант - вашу кастомизированную полоску положить в layout где будет рисунок и текст Загрузка. и всё это сделать одной кастомной вьюхой